# Shell Script is not opening Selenium IE browser on remote machine

Tags: shell, maven, powershell, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

```
I have to execute to automation testing suite on windows remote machine.
We are using generalized Jenkins Server hosted on Unix platform.
```

- Steps Achieved:-

  1) Create SSH Connection and copying my code from GIT Server to Window Machine - Successful
  2) Create shell script which will execute maven command to run the test script - Successful 
  3) Script and Project is successfully executed - Successful
- Issue:-

  I am not able to view the browser launching or execution happening from a shell script when initiated from Jenkins Job
- Observation:

  Standalone execution or local execution of shell script is launching the browser and I am to see the execution of test scripts on the browser
- Shell Script Prepared

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  export SOURCEDIR="/home/***/jenkins/git"
  export DESTDIR="/home/****/jenkins/git/FLIP_Sanity"
  echo "$SOURCEDIR"
  echo "$DESTDIR"
  echo "CURRENT PATH PRINTED"
  pwd
  cd $SOURCEDIR
  echo "Providing rights to the folder for execution"
  chmod  -R 777 $DESTDIR
  echo "Navigation to Destination Folder"
  cd $DESTDIR
  pwd
  echo "Executing maven command"
  echo $PATH
  mvn clean test -Denvironment=QA-Dbrowser=IE -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=Sanity.xml
  ```

  exit

  What change needs to be done on the script or execution to open the interactive browser session

Comment: what about selenium hub?

Comment: I have not tried node & hub.  Since this working I want to check why interactive session is not getting enabled in Window Server 2012